# Mongoose: "TypeError: Undefined type at"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a module that uses mongoose. My main project also uses mongoose. I found out that I can not use module's connection with my project's schema. See the example:

```
var mod = require('module_with_mongoose_connection');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var SessionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({ // replacing this with `mod.mongoose.Schema` works
...
});
mod.mongooseConnection.model('session', SessionSchema);
```

The example above throws

```
    throw new TypeError('Undefined type at `' + path +
          ^
TypeError: Undefined type at `paths.name`
  Did you try nesting Schemas? You can only nest using refs or arrays.
    at Function.Schema.interpretAsType (/Users/me/Work/me/nodejs/orm-model/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema.js:397:11)
    at Schema.path (/Users/me/Work/me/nodejs/orm-model/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema.js:334:29)
    at Schema.add (/Users/me/Work/me/nodejs/orm-model/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema.js:245:12)
    at Schema.add (/Users/me/Work/me/nodejs/orm-model/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema.js:240:14)
    at new Schema (/Users/me/Work/me/nodejs/orm-model/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema.js:72:10)
Why is that? A bug?
```

What's the solution to this problem? A bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found `the solution`. It turns out that the error is thrown only when using local modules (e.g. `require('../module_with_mongoose_connection')`). When using a module over `npm` (inside `node_modules`) it works. The error is also thrown when mongoose connection is `dynamically patched` (e.g. you add an attribute like `mongooseConnection.myattr = 'something'`).

Well this is really weird but I hope this answer will help others.

Comment: May you please expand more how this issue can be solved?Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error, my problem was that I had a spelling mistake in my require statement:

```
var mongoose = require('Mongoose'); // Don't do this

var mongoose = require('mongoose'); // Use a lowercase 'm'
```

Answer (score 0):

So I had this same problem and the answer @xpepermint gave didn't solve my issue but it did lead me down the right track. I had two main folders, each with their own node_modules (e.g. C:\MyDocs\MyProject\Server\node_modules and C:\MyDocs\MyProject\Tests\node_modules). In the example I've given, the test scripts under the "Tests" folder had requires to files in the "Server" folder.